# Format string according to date format

Tags: php, date

There is a string:

```
$time = "2013-07-10T21:00:00.000";
```

How to convert it to the format "2013-07-10 21:00:00"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime("2013-07-10T21:00:00.000");
return strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new \DateTime($time);
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = "2013-07-10T21:00:00.000";
echo date("Y-i-d H:m:s",strtotime($time));
```